# I cannot calculate this because I don't have the discount rate

Tags: interest-rate, investment-strategies, cash-flow

What is the NPV of the following investment? Upfront, it requires an investment of 1598. Then, it generates a cash flow of 774 after one year, 659 after two years, and 623 after three years. After that, the cash flow is expected to grow by 3%. The interest rate is 5%.

Answer (score 1):

NPV is 27990.84

[image]

The infinite sum resolves to a closed form.

[image]

To illustrate with a simple example, infinite cash flows of 100 starting from year 1 with an interest rate of 10%

```
d = 100
a = 0
r = 0.1
x = 0
n = 1

NPV = ((1 + a)^(n - x) d (1 + r)^(1 - n))/(-a + r) = 1000
```

Comment: What is that calculator that can do summation?

Comment: @Flux I used [Mathematica](https://www.wolfram.com/mathematica/).